# Java 8 JDK for Windows 32-bit

Tags: java-8, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to install SQL Developer on Windows 32-bit. Which requires Java 8 JDK, but only 64-bit and above versions are available in downloads. How can I download the JDK 8 32-bit version?

Comment: @AndrewMorton sorry about that i meant SQL Developer

Answer (score 3):

Here Is download Link
[Java SE Development Kit 8u101](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Go for Windows x86

Also view this 
[Why does x86 represent 32bit](https://serverfault.com/questions/188177/why-does-x86-represent-32bit-when-x64-represents-64bit)

Comment: I checked the download links  x32 is not available.

Comment: @Nitya There's no such thing as "x32". You need to download the **x86** version, the link is named: `jdk-8u101-windows-i586.exe` on the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find for this is to download an earlier version of SQL Developer. I installed 3.2.2 version from the link below.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-downloads-v322-2080107.html